# how to generate code for MIB table

Tags: snmp

I have a KAVITA-MIB:

```
KAVITA-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

IMPORTS
    OBJECT-TYPE,MODULE-IDENTITY     FROM SNMPv2-SMI
    TEXTUAL-CONVENTION              FROM SNMPv2-TC;

kavita MODULE-IDENTITY
     LAST-UPDATED "200205290000Z"            -- 29 May 2002, midnight
     ORGANIZATION "net-snmp"
     CONTACT-INFO "postal:   Wes Hardaker
                             P.O. Box 382
                             Davis CA  95617

                   email:    net-snmp-coders@lists.sourceforge.net"
     DESCRIPTION  "A simple mib for demonstration purposes."

::={enterprises 1100}

RowStatus ::= TEXTUAL-CONVENTION
    STATUS       current
    DESCRIPTION
        "The RowStatus textual convention is used to manage the
        creation and deletion of conceptual rows, and is used as the
        value of the SYNTAX clause for the status column of a
        conceptual row."
    SYNTAX   INTEGER {
         -- the following two values are states:
         -- these values may be read or written
         active(1),          -- state:  read/write
         notInService(2),    -- state:  read/write
         notReady(3),        -- state:  read only
         createAndGo(4),     -- action: write only
         createAndWait(5),   -- action: write only
         destroy(6)      -- action: write only
    }


    kavitaScalar OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= {kavita 1}
    kavitaTable OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= {kavita 2}

    scalar1 OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX      Integer32
        MAX-ACCESS  read-write
        STATUS      current
        DESCRIPTION "scalar1"
    DEFVAL { 2 }
    ::= { kavitaScalar 1 }

    scalar2 OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX      Integer32
        MAX-ACCESS  read-write
        STATUS      current
        DESCRIPTION "scalar2"
        DEFVAL { 4 }
    ::= { kavitaScalar 2 }

    kavitaTableOne OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX      SEQUENCE OF kavitaTable1Entry
        MAX-ACCESS  not-accessible
        STATUS      current
        DESCRIPTION "Table 1"
    ::= { kavitaTable 1 }

    kavitaTable1Entry OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX      kavitaTable1Entry
        MAX-ACCESS  not-accessible
        STATUS      current
        DESCRIPTION "Entry"
        INDEX { tIndex }
    ::= { kavitaTableOne 1 }

    kavitaTable1Entry ::= SEQUENCE {
        tIndex      Integer32,
        tName       DisplayString,
        tMarks      Integer32,
        tRowStatus  INTEGER
    }

    tIndex OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX      Integer32 (1..100)
        MAX-ACCESS  read-only
        STATUS      current
        DESCRIPTION "Index for Table 1"
    ::= { kavitaTable1Entry 1 }

    tName OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX      DisplayString
        MAX-ACCESS  read-create
        STATUS      current
        DESCRIPTION "Name for Table 1"
    ::= { kavitaTable1Entry 2 }

    tMarks OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX      Integer32(1..100)
        MAX-ACCESS  read-create
        STATUS      current
        DESCRIPTION "Marks for Table 1"
    ::= { kavitaTable1Entry 3 } 


    tRowStatus OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX     RowStatus
        MAX-ACCESS read-create
        STATUS     current
        DESCRIPTION "The status"
    ::= { kavitaTable1Entry 4 }      

END
```

How should i generate mib2c code for "kavitaTableOne".

I have tried using 
 env MIBS="+KAVITA-MIB" MIBDIRS="/usr/share/snmp/mibs" mib2c -c mib2c.mfd.conf kavitaTableOne

but it says
Unlinked OID in KAVITA-MIB: kavita ::= { enterprises 1100 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 7 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/KAVITA-MIB.txt
This module can only be used with tables, not branches or entire MIBs.
Please specify and OID that is a table. (OID: kavitaTableOne)

Kindly help..

Answer (score 0):

In the top of your MIB you may first repeat :

```
kavita        OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { enterprises 1100 }
```

after that try to compile with :

```
env MIBS="+KAVITA-MIB" mib2c kavitaTable
```

Comment: KAVITA-MIB contains the stmt "kavita OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { enterprises 1100 }"

I tried using "env MIBS="+KAVITA-MIB" mib2c kavitaTable".This works but it generated the file "kavitaTable_oids.h" containing

/* column number definitions for table kavitaTable */
#define COLUMN_KAVITATABLE1ENTRY         1

But I assumed to have something like which conatisn teh OID of individual entries in the tables like

#define COLUMN_tIndex        1
#define COLUMN_tName        2
#define COLUMN_tMarks        3
#define COLUMN_tRowStatus        4

Comment: I have also added the whole MIB by editing the question's content.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to import `enterprises`:

```
IMPORTS
    OBJECT-TYPE,MODULE-IDENTITY,enterprises     FROM SNMPv2-SMI
```